# Why are "narayana" and "vishnu" merged as tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonyms

First of all it is a sectarian position that they are the same.  But by that logic all 1000 names of Vishnu can be merged under Vishnu

Answer (score -2):

I am adding another answer, since the atmosphere of HSE seems to have improved a little from the time I asked the above question.

[Are Vaishnavastra and Narayanastra the same?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/51152/are-vaishnavastra-and-narayanastra-the-same)

CLEARLY - "Vaishnava(adjective)" and "Narayana(adjective)" are different.

**"Shiva" and "Rudra" are different tags at HSE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

There is a fair number of instances where Narayana means something different from Vishnu.  For example, in Brahma Vaivarta Purana Krishna creates Vishnu and Narayana separately.

under this question

[Is the argument that "Narayana" can only denote Vishnu correct?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32788/is-the-argument-that-narayana-can-only-denote-vishnu-correct)

a moderator writes

@SK tag Narayana was merged with Vishnu as synonym. But that is not sectarian. Narayana usually refers to Vishnu. But it is not correct to say Narayana is proper noun. –
The Destroyer
♦
Feb 8, 2019 at 13:48

Actually "narayana"  **always** denoting Vishnu **alone** is a crucial position for some sects.

In reality most deity-names are used for multiple deities, since there are hardly any proper nouns in Sanskrit.

In the interest of fairness, can these two tags be separated?

Answer (score -7):

This doesn't seem to be correct - since THE ACTUAL PRACTICE of Hindus shows belief in a  Narayana who is not the Narayana of Vaishnavites:

https://archive.org/stream/OchreRobeSwamiAgehanandaBharati/Ochre%20Robe%20Swami%20Agehananda%20Bharati_djvu.txt

> Narsingh Baba (he has nothing but the name in common with 
>   Narsingh Giri, the Abbot of the Qudsia Ghat Dasanaml-Math), 
>   the leader of the Naga group that had come to join the assembly, 
>   and his group consisted of about a dozen naked monks. He is a 
>   graduate from some Indian university, and had renounced the 
>   world soon after leaving college. When he was introduced to 
>   me, I greeted him with 'NamahSivaya, i.e. ‘Victory unto Siva', 
>   as a token of respect for his particular tutelary deity. He shook 
>   his head and said solemnly; ‘No, Maharaj, don't you know how 
>   sadhus greet each other?' ‘Of course,' I replied; ‘the general 
>   salute is Om Namo Narayanaya , but do you not object to 
>   N dr ay ana as a somewhat sectarian term?' Ndr ay ana usually 
>   refers to Visnu, and there is some sectarian discrimination 
>   between the Siva and the Visnu aspect of Divinity. ‘Not 
>   at all,’ Narsingh Baba replied, ‘and even if I did object, 
>   the N dr ay ana of the sa^M-salute is not the Naray ana of the 
>   Vaisnavas except by metaphysical generalization. No sadhii, of 
>   whatever personal predilection, should use a different salute, 
>   whatever he feels about “Narayana".' I was amazed at this 
>   statement for, though of course there is nothing new in his 
>   metaphysical disquisition—almost all divine epithets apply 
>   equally to all gods of the Hindu pantheon,